# Git syntactic sugar for "current branch"?

Tags: git, version-control

I know that in git you can use `-` to refer to the previous branch you were on.

So for example, if I'm in the `tester` branch and run `git checkout master`, then decide I want to go back to `tester`, I could run `git checkout -` instead of `git checkout tester`.

#### My question is this:

Is there some kind of syntactic sugar in git that allows me to reference the **current branch** I'm in?

So for instance, if I'm in `master` and want to run `git pull origin master`, could I run instead `git pull origin {current branch sugar}`?

It's mostly just getting annoying having to specify the current branch name for common commands like `push`, `pull`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, a `git pull` should be enough, provided your branch is set with an upstream branch

```
git branch -u origin/master master
```

So it isn't so much a syntactic sugar which reference the current branch: this is more default parameters of git commands.
For [`git pull`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) for instance:

> Default values for `<repository>` and `<branch>` are read from the "`remote`" and "`merge`" configuration for the *current branch* as set by [`git-branch --track`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch).